# Vantara GT 6061 aluminum bike front wheel replacement?

Tags: rims, front

I have a Vantara GT 6061 aluminum bike and I lost the front wheel. Where can I get a replacement?

Comment: The significant factors are the diameter of the wheel (ie, 26 inch, 28 inch, 700c or whatever), the type of brakes (rim or disk), the type of axle (quick release or not), and, to a lesser degree, the width of the rim and tire.  You can get the tire/wheel dimensions off the rear tire, assuming they were identical.

Comment: And note that 29-inch and 700c are actually the same size.  See [Sheldon Brown's page](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) to decipher the tire sizing madness.  The reliable reference is the "ISO" size on the side of the tire, a number like "20-622".

Comment: Also consider Presta or Schrader valve, not critical but does make carrying a spare tube simpler.

Comment: I'd try the place from where I bought the bike!

Comment: You need a wheel, rim tape, tyre, and an innertube too.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is: any good bike store. You may not be able to get an exact match for the hub and rim GT used origigally, but you will be able to get a wheel that is functionally identical.

If you understand bicycle wheel standards, you could source a replacement wheel from an online store for little less cost, but if you do not, it's much easier to have a local bike store advise you.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google for "Vantara GT 6061 specs" returns [this sports shop](https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/gt-mens-vantara-comp-hybrid-bike-16gtxa700cmgtvntrfbb/16gtxa700cmgtvntrfbb)  which says

- Wheel Size: 700c
- Hub (F): Formula Alloy 28h with QR
- Tires: Kenda Kwest 700x28c
- Tektro RX-1 Brakes

So your front wheel needs to have

- Quick Release axle to match the frame mounts
- a 700c wheel (which is "622" in modern wheel sizing"
- a rim width of 15/17/19mm
- a 28mm tyre (because that will fit inside your frame)
- A RIM BRAKE track around the outside (ie it must not be a disk brake only wheel)

So the wheel is 700c, the tyre is 28-622, and the axle must be a QR.

I can't tell if its a Presta or Schrader valve, probably the former.  You can look at the valve on your back wheel to see which it is.

I also can't advise on how many spokes your wheel needs.  The original spec was 28 spokes, but you could choose to have more or fewer.  Doesn't really matter unless you're a bigger rider where more spokes is better.